# How to generate a failure at runtime in an xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, runtime

I need to generate a runtime error in an xslt.  How to do so?

The following xpaths do not generate runtime errors:

- "1 div 0"
- "/*/*[1 div 0]"
- "/*/*[0]"
- "/*/*[NaN]"

It does not have to be done using xpath, could be done using some xslt construct.

The reason I want this is to effectively have a "NotImplementedException" in my xslt.  There is a specific path that will not be used any time soon, so I do not want to implement it yet.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for XSLT 2.0/XPath 2.0 specific solution.

Comment: Good to know about 2.0.  I upvoted your answer because it is useful, but the currently accepted one is still the most portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can terminate an XSL script and deliver a message using the [`xsl:message`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_message.asp) element.

```
<xsl:message terminate="yes">
  NotImplementedException
</xsl:message>
```

Answer (score 3):

**In addidtion to `<xsl:message>` in XSLT 2.x one can use the standard XPath 2.0 function [`error()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-error)**.